# Determining a file size using File class

Tags: java

I am playing around with the file class in java. I was trying to determine the size of a file so I used the length() method. My output was 0 for the given code I used.

```
File test=new File("hello.pdf");
System.out.println(test.length());
```

First, am I using length properly?(as in does it determine the file size or am I reading javadocs wrong?)

Second, if I am using length in the right context, why is it 0? Thanks.

Comment: You can do the same with this : Files.size(new File(filename).toPath()).

Comment: Yes it returns zero because it is an empty file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
File test=new File("hello.pdf");

if(test.exists()){
 double bytes = test.length();
 double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
 double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);

 System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes);
 System.out.println("kilobytes : " + kilobytes);
 System.out.println("megabytes : " + megabytes);
}else{
 System.out.println("File does not exists!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a hello.pdf file in the directory? If not, then you've just created an empty one and it's 0 bytes long.

Comment: What is its length? It's also likely that if you tell Java new File("hello.pdf") it created an empty PDF in your home directory.

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what the length is since it keeps returning 0 is there another way to look at it?

Comment: Use a file explorer like Windows Explorer, the Finder on a Mac, the commmand line or console, etc. There are a million ways to find out the file's length.

Comment: @user2910237 Always specify the *full path* to the file when using the File object. And always use exists() as Bishan does in his answer. If you don't use the full path you're using the current directory or the home directory.